# Angular JS does not reflect changes in $scope object of controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have seen some questions similar to this one, but I cannot resolve my issue.
I have angular controller:

```
app.controller('MyFormCtrl', function($scope, Item) {

    $scope.searchResult = {value: 'Test'};

    $scope.search = function() {
        console.log($scope.searchResult);
        $scope.searchResult.value = "Clicked";
    }
}
```

And html template:

```
<div ng-controller="MyFormCtrl">
  <p>{{searchResult.value}}</p>
  <p align="center"><a href="#" ng-click="search()">Search</a></p>
</div>
```

And I cannot force it to reflect changes that are made in controller. At load I see default values of variables: 'Test' and 'Test name'. But when I click register button new values are assinged to variables in controller, but no changes at html page. I suppose there is some problem with scopes. I'm new at angularjs and SO cannot help me, so I suppose it is time for some special help on my particular case.

**Update 1.** Item - is a resource to rest api, it works and I see result in firebug during debugging, but it does not matter. Even if I delete this line, nevertheless searchResult does not update. But in JS console after 1st click I see value 'Test' (it is correct), on second click I see in cosole value 'Clicked', which means that new value were assinged, I see the same during debug in firebug, but on html page I still see value 'Test'.
I have tried to do $scope.$apply() - it does not help. The most closest case that I managed to find are this question: [changing a controller scope variable in a directive is not reflected in controller function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27532978/changing-a-controller-scope-variable-in-a-directive-is-not-reflected-in-controll), but here I see more complex logic.

**Update 2.** There are a lot of answers, which were confused with Item call. I have deleted Items call, and make code as simple as it possible. It still does not reflect changes of variable searchResult.

**Update 3.**
There is no issue, I have started from simple example and get working result, seems like and introduced some error in initial project during.

Comment: If `Item.search()` errors out, `$scope.searchResult.value = "Clicked";` is never reached. Have you tried removing that line?

Comment: You will probably need to clarify your question a bit more.  Specifically, what the `Item.search()` function does.   There isn't anything obvious about the code that you have posted here that would explain why it's not functioning.

Comment: Does `Item.search()` return a different array of objects? Because if it is not returning anything then `$scope.searchItems` won't update from the click event.

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: I have created plunker for above code.Its working for me.http://plnkr.co/edit/c3uAyEVPUJ1A12iVl0U6?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

> t is Working you are using **Item params** in controller remove it and
>   see it works and if you are using angular new one then use angular
>   module

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" >
  <div ng-controller="myFormCtrl">
  <p>{{searchResult.value}}</p>
  <p align="center"><a href="#" ng-click="search()">Search</a></p>
</div>
  </div>

<script>
  var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller('myFormCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.searchResult = {value: 'Test'};

    $scope.search = function() {
        console.log($scope.searchResult);
        $scope.searchResult.value = "Clicked";
    }
})
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The AngularJS documentation has an example for this.  Start there and incrementally introduce your `Item.search()` function

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: Not sure how filter could help me? Could you please explain a little more detailed.