# AngularJS call callback after update two way binding values in component

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
  myApp.component('example', {
    template: '<button type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.click()">click me</button>',
    bindings: { value: '=', callback: '&' },
    controller: function () {
      this.click = function () {
        this.value = 'clicked';
        this.callback();
      }.bind(this);
    },
  });

  myApp.component('useExample', {
    template: '<example value="$ctrl.value" callback="$ctrl.callback()"></example>',
    controller: function () {
      this.callback = function () { alert(this.value); }.bind(this);
    },
  });
```

Here are two components, while the second one use the first one.

The first component change `this.value` and then call `callback`. But when the second one `alert(this.value)`, it got empty value instead of `'clicked'` first time. It seems that the `this.value` in `useExample` did not be updated when the callback is triggered.

I want get new value instead of old one.

I have attempted to change `this.callback()` in `example` to something like `$timeout(function () { this.callback(); }.bind(this), 0)`, and it works. But I think there should be some better way to do so.

So, my question is what is the best way I should do to make `useExample` read new `this.value` in the callback.

**-- Update 1 --**

I would prefer not to change the given interface.

**-- Update 2 --**

aha, i just searched out this topic: [AngularJS: Parent scope is not updated in directive (with isolated scope) two way binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557599/angularjs-parent-scope-is-not-updated-in-directive-with-isolated-scope-two-wa) . It seems that this question is duplicate to that one. and i have read posts on that question, it seems `$timeout` is the best(?) way, wt*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS: Parent scope is not updated in directive (with isolated scope) two way binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557599/angularjs-parent-scope-is-not-updated-in-directive-with-isolated-scope-two-wa)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the watcher that binds the value from child scope to parent scope executes on a micro-thread (fiber) subsequent to the invocation of the function in the expression binding.

The solution is to expose the value as a local in the expression binding:

```
myApp.component('example', {
    template: '<button type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.click()">click me</button>',
    bindings: { 
        callback: '&' 
    },
    controller: function () {
      this.click =  () => {
        this.value = 'clicked';
        //EXPOSE this.value as $value
        this.callback({$value: this.value});
      };
    },
});
```

In the above example, the value is exposed as `$value`.

Use the exposed value as an argument of callback function:

```
myApp.component('useExample', {
    template: '<example callback="$ctrl.useCallback($value)"></example>',
    controller: function () {
      this.useCallback = (v) => { alert(v); };
    },
});
```

Because the value is provided as an argument of the callback, the value is immediately available.

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k1yb4suk/).

Comment: pass the value in callback is not what i want. since it would change the interface of my component, and make caller more confuse. (caller is not written by me)

Comment: I just want it works as what `<input ng-model="value" ng-change="callback()" />` do, which looks better to me and seems to be more 'stander' way.